# How can I open a Visual Studio Web Site in another PC without losing all my breakpoints?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

At my office PC I am working on a web site using Visual Studio 2012. I created several breakpoints (using F9) in the code-behind of several pages.

I made a copy of the whole web site folder and then opened it again in another PC (using the same version of VS2012).

Now all my breakpoints are gone.

How can I open a Visual Studio Web Site in another PC without losing all my breakpoints?

Thanks in advance.

CD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project's .suo file has the breakpoint information. Try copying the .suo and replacing the other pc's .suo file.

If you're unfamiliar with it, the project solution file (e.g. "MyProject.sln") has an associated file, the Solution User Options file (e.g. "MyProject.suo"), which stores various information, including breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you! I now have my .sln and my .suo files both in the same folder as the rest of the web site. My project is portable now!